# FormatNumber for c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Im struggling to get the right syntax to use in c# for the vb function FormatNumber...i will say that 'iPremium' is an object as it returns data from a tableadapter.

the value that 'ipremium' holds is 943.4000 and the idea is to only have two decimal places after the '.', i would hope this is acheivable using the right syntax but unfortunately not being a c# expert, it could take a while to figure this out.

here's the vb code:

```
  iPremium = FormatNumber(iPremium, 2, TriState.True)
```

any idea's on how this is acheivable?

thanks for any idea's and suggestions and excuse the ignorance if this is not worded correctly

Comment: look up string.Format() method

Answer (score 5):

```
var formattedNumber = iPremium.ToString("0.00");
```

or, if you wish to round the number, instead of just chopping-off precision:

```
var formattedNumber = Math.Round(iPremium, 2).ToString("0.00").Dump();
```

Here's a list of the various formats you can use with ToString: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: what is Dump function ?

Comment: @Kiquenet - Ignore that - it's a function within Linqpad, a great code snippet compiler thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var roundedNumber = Math.Round(iPremium, 2);
var formattedNumber = String.Format("{0:#.##}", roundedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `TableAdapter` returns a `Datatable` which can also be used strongly typed:

```
// first row as example (add using.System.Linq)
double value = table.AsEnumerable().First().Field<double>("iPremium");
```

Now you can use `String.Format` or just `ToString` with a custom format:

```
string result = value.ToString("0.00");
```